# Linq query using only year part of datetime

Tags: c#, sql, linq

One of the column in my sqlserver table is datetime. In the where clause I have query just by the year (not month and date). I have to do it in LINQ using C#. Please let me know how could do it.

For example if the following are the values in the table

02/12/2010
07/14/2011
11/15/2012

and if I query by '2011', only the middle row should be fetched.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

this can be done quite easily. See the example below

```
List<DateTime> test=new List<DateTime>{DateTime.Today,DateTime.Today.AddDays(3),DateTime.Today.AddYears(1),DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddYears(1)};

    test.Where (c => c.Year==2013).Dump();
    test.Where (c => c.Year==2012).Dump();
```

the result would be

```
5IEnumerable<DateTime> (2 items) 4  
11/5/2013 12:00:00 AM 
11/6/2013 12:00:00 AM 

5IEnumerable<DateTime> (2 items) 4  
11/5/2012 12:00:00 AM 
11/8/2012 12:00:00 AM
```

EDIT:
The Dump() function is part of LINQPad. It's not a native .NET method. Remove it to test outside of LINQPad.